# Entity Framework TPH with multiple abstract inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, table-per-hierarchy

I'm trying to do a Table Per Hierarchy model in Entity Framework(VS 2008 sp1, 3.5).

Most of my models have been very simple, an abstract type with multiple sub-types that inherit from it.

However, I've been struggling with this latest challenge.  I have STUDENTS that I'd like to inherit from PERSONS(abstract) that should inherity from PARTIES(abstract).

Every time I do this I get a "Error 2078: The EntityType 'Model.PERSONS' is Abstract and can be mapped only using IsTypeOf."  I guess the problem is PARTIES is already defined as IsTypeOf in the entity set.

So is this even possible?  I can work around it by making PERSONS abstract = false and assigning a bogus conditional mapping.  But this seems like a silly workaround.

Comment: Follow up question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045924/multiple-inheritance-with-entity-framework-with-tph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the model using XML Editor: find the mapping and add IsTypeOf to the corresponding EntityTypeMapping tag. 
Here is an example resembling your case: 
SQL Server DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PartyInfo] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PersonInfo] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [StudInfo] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Student] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (  [Id] ASC  )
  )
```

EDMX:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" 
xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
<!-- EF Runtime content -->
<edmx:Runtime>
<!-- SSDL content -->
<edmx:StorageModels>
  <Schema Namespace="test_1Model.Store" Alias="Self" 
Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" 
xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="test_1ModelStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="Student" EntityType="test_1Model.Store.Student" 
store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="Student">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Id" Type="int" Nullable="false" 
StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="PartyInfo" Type="varchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="PersonInfo" Type="varchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="StudInfo" Type="varchar(max)" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema>
</edmx:StorageModels>
<!-- CSDL content -->
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="test_1Model" Alias="Self" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm">
    <EntityContainer Name="test_Entities">
      <EntitySet Name="PartySet" EntityType="test_1Model.Party" />
    </EntityContainer>
    <EntityType Name="Party" Abstract="true">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="Id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
      <Property Name="PartyInfo" Type="String" Nullable="false" 
MaxLength="Max" Unicode="false" FixedLength="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="Person" BaseType="test_1Model.Party" Abstract="true" >
      <Property Name="PersonInfo" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityType Name="Student" BaseType="test_1Model.Person" >
      <Property Name="StudInfo" Type="String" Nullable="false" />
    </EntityType>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
<!-- C-S mapping content -->
<edmx:Mappings>
  <Mapping Space="C-S" 
xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:windows:storage:mapping:CS">
    <EntityContainerMapping 
StorageEntityContainer="test_1ModelStoreContainer" 
CdmEntityContainer="test_Entities">
      <EntitySetMapping Name="PartySet">
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(test_1Model.Party)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Student">
            <ScalarProperty Name="PartyInfo" ColumnName="PartyInfo" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(test_1Model.Person)">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Student">
            <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="PersonInfo" ColumnName="PersonInfo" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
        <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="test_1Model.Student">
          <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Student">
            <ScalarProperty Name="PartyInfo" ColumnName="PartyInfo" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="PersonInfo" ColumnName="PersonInfo" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
            <ScalarProperty Name="StudInfo" ColumnName="StudInfo" />
          </MappingFragment>
        </EntityTypeMapping>
     </EntitySetMapping>
  </EntityContainerMapping>
</Mapping>
</edmx:Mappings>
</edmx:Runtime>
<!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
<edmx:Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
    <edmx:Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" 
Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </edmx:Connection>
  <edmx:Options>
    <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
      <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
    </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
  </edmx:Options>
  <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
  <edmx:Diagrams>
    <Diagram Name="SqlServer_Model" />
  </edmx:Diagrams>
</edmx:Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Comment: Interesting.. So it seems I have to make all entities TypeOf in the "C-S" mapping space if they are abstract.  Any Entities that are not abstract do not need this edited.  Your example helped, thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay (holidays and I wanted to ensure I got it right)